# Updating an MsAccess database that has Short Text and Number type of fields in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, oledb

I have `Textboxes` and I want to update my `database` using these `Textboxes`. I have tried removing the ' ' symbols in the `Regular` and `OT` database field in my `Query` but I still
keep getting this error when I press my `Button`:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: Data type mismatch in criteria expression.
```

NOTE: The `Regular` and `OT` field are both `Number` types in the database whilst evertything is `Short Text`.

This is my `OLEdb` statement:

```
"UPDATE dataNA SET today = '" & datestring & "', 
ProjectCode = '" & PrjctCodePassLbl.Text & "', 
Project = '" & PrjctNameTxtBox.Text & "', 
Mark = '" & MarkTxtBox.Text & "', 
Activity = '" & ActvtyTxtBox.Text & "', 
Regular = '" & Integer.Parse(RglrTxtBox.Text) & "', 
OT = '" & Integer.Parse(OTTxtBox.Text) & "' 

WHERE today = '" & DateLbl.Text & "' AND ProjectCode = '" & PrjctCodePassLbl.Text & "' 
AND Project = '" & PrjctNameLbl.Text & "' 
AND Mark = '" & MarkLbl.Text & "' 
AND Activity = '" & ActvtyLbl.Text & "' 
AND Regular = '" & RglrLbl.Text & "' 
AND OT = '" & OTLbl.Text & "' "
```

Comment: Stop using string concatenations to build sql query. Use parameters. More safe, more clear.

Comment: Check your database fields. Are they all strings? You are passing the values as they were strings but if one or more columns expect a different datatype the mentioned error kicks in. Again parameterized query could solve the problem

Comment: @Steve: So I should assign values to my TextBox.Text for less errors? The Regular and OT field is a Number.

Comment: @Steve: I should declare Strings then pass the TextBox value there?

Answer (score 0):

You should use a parameterized query specifying the datatype of every parameter that you add to your query. In this way the DB Engine knows exactly how to handle your values and assign them to your query with the appropriate quotes when required.

I will give you an example (incomplete but this should give you a valid starting point)

```
Dim sql = "UPDATE dataNA SET today = @dt, " & _
          "ProjectCode = @pcode, " & _
          "Project = @prj, " & _
          "Mark = @mark, " & _
          "Activity = @activity, " & _
          "Regular = @regular, " & _
          "OT = @ot " & _
          "WHERE today = @dt1 AND ProjectCode = @pcode1 " & _
          "AND Project = @prj1 "&  
          "AND Mark = @mark1 " & _
          "AND Activity = @activity1 " & _
          "AND Regular = @regular1 " & _
          "AND OT = @ot1 "
 Using cnn = new OleDbConnection(... connectionstring here....)
 Using cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, cnn)
     cnn.Open()
     With cmd
         .Parameters.Add("@dt", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = datestring 
         .Parameters.Add("@pcode", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = PrjctCodePassLbl.Text 
         ... and so on with all the other parameters...
         ... remember that with OleDb you need to add them 
         ... to the parameters collection in the same EXACT order 
         ... in which they appear in the sql string.
         ... Of course every parameter should have the correct 
         ... OleDbType expected by your table, for example
         .Parameters.Add("@regular", OleDbType.Integer).Value = Integer.Parse(RglrTxtBox.Text)
         ... finally call
     End With
     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery
 End Using
 End Using
```

Check [OleDbType enum here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbtype(v=vs.110).aspx)

Probably your error is caused by putting quotes around the values for the two integers value both in the update and in the WHERE clause. In any case a parameterized query avoid these mishaps.

Comment: I'll try this tomorrow. I left the office.

Answer (score 0):

I removed the ' ' (single quotes) on the `UPDATE` and `WHERE` of Regular and OT and it works

```
"UPDATE dataNA SET today = '" & datestring & "', 
ProjectCode = '" & PrjctCodePassLbl.Text & "', 
Project = '" & PrjctNameTxtBox.Text & "', 
Mark = '" & MarkTxtBox.Text & "', 
Activity = '" & ActvtyTxtBox.Text & "', 
Regular = " & Integer.Parse(RglrTxtBox.Text) & ", 
OT = " & Integer.Parse(OTTxtBox.Text) & " 
WHERE today = '" & DateLbl.Text & "' AND 
ProjectCode = '" & PrjctCodePassLbl.Text & "' AND 
Project = '" & PrjctNameLbl.Text & "' AND 
Mark = '" & MarkLbl.Text & "' AND 
Activity = '" & ActvtyLbl.Text & "' AND 
Regular = " & Integer.Parse(RglrLbl.Text) & " AND 
OT = " & Integer.Parse(OTLbl.Text) & " "
```

Comment: Well, now try to put a single quote inside any of your textboxes. For example: `PrjctNameTxtBox.Text = "Man's work"`